# Pandas tralling .0 issue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am facing an issue in data frame of removing `.0`

My data looks like

```
Age
3.5
9.0
7.6
8.7
4.0
```

And I want it to looks like

```
 Age
 3.5
 9
 7.6
 8.7
 4
```

It's only a sample, the real data frame is too big with more than 50 columns having the same problem,
so please suggest me the answer which can directly be applied to the whole data frame instead of individual columns.

I am trying to convert by below method but it's not working

```
def myconverter(o):
if isinstance(o, float):
    if o == int(o):
        return int(o)
return o.__str__()



org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "309.0"
```

Comment: what is the usecase for this?

Comment: No, it's not helpful in my case because I have too many columns with different data types so I can't apply this column-based approach

Answer (score 0):

You could probably apply `if` condition

```
def transform_value(val):
    if val % 1 == 0: #val is the value for which you are checking
        return (int(val))
    else:
        return val

df['value'] = df['value'].apply(transform_value) #for single columns
df = df.apply(transform_value) # for entire dataframe
```

Hopefully, this answers it. I am interested in knowing the use case of why you need that.

Comment: I am transferring data from one database to another based on the date, So in this case, I am having a huge data frame.
And my error is 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "309.0"
Your suggestion is good but it's not solving my problem

def myconverter(o):
    if isinstance(o, float):
        if o == int(o):
            return int(o)
    return o.__str__()

Comment: I have edited the code. please try now, once transformed, the database can be exported. do you think it might help?

Comment: After applying the method I am getting this error on 
df.columns = map(str.upper, df.columns) 
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'

Comment: if you want to apply to the entire dataframe then use `df = df.apply(transform_value)` and if you want just for one column please use the name of that column. In your case, I guess you want to apply to the entire frame. the last two lines of my answer may answer your this comment